# How can I confirm that 'react-native-vector-icons' are already installed on my system?

Tags: command-line, react-native

I believe I have previously installed react-native icon set already on windows 10. I'm not sure if it's there, if it successfully installed etc. How can I work this out?

Originally I believe I used:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons
```

I want to type a command that confirms it is installed or be able to locate where it has be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is located in the `node_modules` file in the project you created.

In `'node_modules'` file:

[image]

You can also try it yourself to see if it's installed.

You can either use one of the bundled icons above or roll your own custom font.

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myIcon = <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />;
```

And if it's up to date, it's created in the `node_modules` folder since the project was created.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `package.json` file. If it's installed it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **package.json** you should see something like this *"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",*. make sure you do **react-native link react-native-vector-icons** and restart the packager to use icons.Also to confirm it you can find the folder named *react-native-vector-icons* in **projectName/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons**. Also try using it once to check that there is no problem with your installation and linking of the npm module

```
 import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
 <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />;
```

It will render the correct icon if you have followed all the steps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for npm package for particular project by navigating to that particular project directory and run command `npm list <Your Package>`

So for `react-native-vector-icons` the command is `npm list react-native-vector-icons`

If you don't know the location then you can search it globally by `npm list <package name> -g`

So for `react-native-vector-icons` the command is `npm list react-native-vector-icons -g`

result will be like below:

```
projectName@projectVersion /path/to/project/folder
└── react-native-vector-icons@6.3.0
```